# Creating a new "object" column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, conditional-statements

I want to create a new column. The column should consist of the part of the day for example "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening" and "Night". I have a column called "DepTime" which consists of army time. Using this as a condition:

Morning 500  to 1159

Afternoon 1200 to 1659

Evening 1700 to 2059

Night 2100 to 400

I want to create my new column to like this:

```
Output[]: 
         DepTime    PartofDay
          1300        Noon
          2400        Night
```

It throws an error but I have tried it this way:

```
for time in flight_data["DepTime"]:
    if flight_data_explored[time].map(lambda x: 500 if x > 1 else 1159):
             flight_data_explored["PartofDay"] = "Morning"
```

Is there a way, to do such a condition. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
mask1 = df.DepTime.between(500, 1159)
mask2 = df.DepTime.between(1200,1659)
mask3 = df.DepTime.between(1700,2059)

df['PartofDay1'] = np.where(mask1, 'Morning', 
                   np.where(mask2, 'Afternoon',
                   np.where(mask3, 'Evening', 'Night')))

print (df)
   DepTime PartofDay PartofDay1
0     1300      Noon  Afternoon
1     2400     Night      Night
```

Comment: Hey thanks it works ! but one thing when i tried to create a mask4 for "Night" it throws an error... howcome I cannot create mask4 with "Night"? @jezrael

Comment: Then need `mask4 = df.DepTime.between(2100,2400) | df.DepTime.between(0,400)`, but it is not necessary ;)

Comment: I had a second issue that I tagged you in, if its not much you mind taking a look @jezrael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356533/mapping-the-index-of-the-feat-importances-to-the-index-of-columns-in-a-dataframe @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

**Data:**

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   DepTime
0        0
1      400
2      500
3     1100
4     1200
5     1600
6     1700
7     1900
8     2100
9     2359
```

**Solution:**

```
bins = [0, 700, 1200, 1600, 2400]
labels = ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night']

df['PartofDay'] = pd.cut(df.DepTime - 500 + 2400*(df.DepTime < 500),
                         bins=bins,
                         labels=labels,
                         right=False)
```

**Result:**

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
   DepTime  PartofDay
0        0      Night
1      400      Night
2      500    Morning
3     1100    Morning
4     1200  Afternoon
5     1600  Afternoon
6     1700    Evening
7     1900    Evening
8     2100      Night
9     2359      Night
```